# Display gallery on top before content

Tags: functions, shortcode, gallery

Is it possible to execute the gallery shortcode before any other content no matter where the shortcode is in the post HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function gallery_first( $content) {
    $expr = '/\[gallery(.*?)\]/i';
    return preg_replace_callback( $expr, create_function('$matches', 'return do_shortcode($matches[0]);'), $content);
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'gallery_first', 6); // prio 6 executes this function previous to all other filter functions
```

Comment: Thank you! I added the code to functions but for some reason it doesn't work. I added the gallery shortcode below some text but the it does not appear above.

Comment: Sorry, the title of your question differs a bit from the description text. My first solution was to place the gallery at the start of the text but I modified it after reading the text of your question again. Now any gallery shortcode is simply executed before all other filters assigned to that hook. I will place the other variant as an additional answer, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
function gallery_first( $content) {
    $expr = '/\[gallery(.*?)\]/i';
    return (" [gallery] " . preg_replace( $expr, '', $content)); // deletes all existing gallery shortcodes
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'gallery_first', 6); // level '6' executes this function previous to all other filter functions
```